# Missing dependency for local prediction: No module named ml.prediction

Tags: google-cloud-ml-engine

Running

```
gcloud ml-engine local predict \
  --model-dir=... \
  --text-instances=... \
  --verbosity=debug
```

throws a `No module named ml.prediction` error.

`gcloud --version`

Google Cloud SDK 155.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading Google Cloud SDK to 157.0.0 fixes the module import error.

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install google-cloud-sdk`

It's not clear from the [release notes](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/release-notes#google_cloud_ml_engine), but perhaps `local predict` was a beta command.